# Change sonid frequency in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I want to change sonid frequency if a button is pressed. I'm using Pygame, specifically the mixer module. When I set the frecuency for the first time I can't set again. I have read the Pygame's docs and exist the `pre_init()` method, this set the frequency before that music play. Right now I have this:

```
def play_full(self, frequency=22050):
    """Play if a button is pressed"""
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=frequency)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../music/hi.mp3"))
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

But the frequency doesn't change with I send the parameter to the function. How I can change the frequency according to button pressed?, Are there some example?. By the way, I'm using PyQt4 for GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pygame.mixer.init() you need to set the frequency the size and the channels,
In your case you will write a code like this:

```
import pygame.mixer

def play_full(self, my_frequency):
    pygame.mixer.init(my_frequency, size=-16, channels=2)
    pygame.mixer.music.load('YOUR_FILE_DIRECTORY_GO_HERE')
    pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

That way you can set frequency for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Gustavo, I'm gonig to test and coming back soon.